# Algorithm for finding last value in sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently making data structures library and now I am trying to make few algorithms that would work with those data structures.

Instead of working with iterators, I am using concept of ranges, and instead of single category tag, I am using two distinct tags: one for traversal & one for accessing elements. I have following traversal concepts: one directional range, two directional range & random access range, and following access concepts: immutable range & mutable range.

I would like to ask if it makes any sense to actually implement some algorithm that will find last occurrence in sequence or allow only for bidirectional ranges to implement this using reversed range.

I know how to implement the algorithm using one directional range, but what should be the return value of such an algorithm in case that element is not present in range? When I want to find last occurrence in one directional range, I actually traverse from begin to end. When I do same algorithm with bidirectional range I traverse from rbegin to rend. Does it makes any sense to return one-past-last element if that element is not present in range for one directional range?

Comment: If you can 1) access any element and 2) know the size of the range. Then you can access the last element.

Comment: You have to signify "_not found_" somehow and you should be consistent about it. Unless you know better copying what the STL does seems like a good idea.

Comment: You could simply use [`std::find_end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_end)

Comment: Thanks for answers. Yes but for FindFirst it seems quite intuitive that when element is not present, it will return one-past-last. What should be intuitive answer for element-not-found in find last algorithm? One-before-begin?

Comment: @AlexanderBily What about STL's `rend`?

Comment: I am talking about the case for one directional ranges like forward list for example.

Comment: The iterator-range "concept" knows only one valid iterator that is not considered part of the range itself, and that's one-past-last. It is useful that returning this iterator as a signal for "not found" is consistent in the whole algorithm library (if that is possible).

Comment: Another reason to always use one-past-the-end to signal "not found": if the special sentinel value depended on the iterator category, then it would no longer be possible to write function templates that call your `find_last()` function, and which work on all container types.  (Not to mention that it would be totally confusing for ordinary users of your function to have to check what iterator category their container provides before knowing which sentinel value to test for!)